# complex mysql query DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

I want to get count how much 'teams' have 5 or more 'paid=1' players.

I tried..

> SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT team) FROM players WHERE paid=1

...but result is 32 where 27 teams have paid 5 players, 5 have paid less than 5.

How to edit this query to get only count teams where paid=1 is >=5?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the teams and take only those having the condition you require. Then count those teams

```
select count(*)
from
(
    SELECT team
    FROM players
    group by team
    having sum(paid=1) >= 5
) tmp
```

Comment: result of this isn't 27 but a lot of rows with number how much players have team (5, 6, 7)

Comment: you are awesome, big thanks for you, i've never did complex query like this!

Comment: Better add `WHERE paid = 1` instead of the `SUM(condition)`, then it's a simple `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5`

Comment: @dnoeth: How is that better? You would need an additional where clause for that. I find it my way more readable.

Comment: The `WHERE` reduces the number of rows to be aggregated, depending how the optimizer will actually process the aggregation this might be more efficient. And it's probably easier to understand :-)